# вставка в БД таблицу с autoincrement

Tags: php, mysql

Как мне вставлять в таблицу данные, если одно из полей `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Например, таблица из двух полей `id` и `name`:

```
CREATE TABLE 'tb'.'gfdg' ( 'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 'name' TEXT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто не указываете `AUTO_INCREMENT` поле в списке вставляемых полей и все.

```
INSERT INTO gfdg (name) VALUES ('Meer');
```

Answer (score 1):

Для автоинкрементного поля можно вставлять значение NULL или 0

```
INSERT INTO gfdg VALUES (0, 'name');
```